# Como hacer mongoimport desde terminal

Tags: mongodb

Hola buenas quiero insertar dos documentos a mi base de datos en mi coleccion 'movieList' pero asi no funciona y no se porque, podria hacerlo desde robomongo si pero quiero hacer mongoimport --db movies --collection --movieList --file movies.json 
Me da error de que mi documento empieza por 'd' (Failed: error processing document #1: invalid character ‘d’ looking for beginning of value), pense que se puede importar asi...

```js
db.getCollection("movieList").insertMany([
{"nombre": "Pirates of the Caribbean",
  "cast": ["Leonardo Di Caprio", "Johnny Depp", "Jennifer Anniston"],
  "director": {
    "nombre": "Christopher nolan",
    "contacto":[
      {
        "tipo": "personal",
        "direccion": "calle isaac albeniz 15, Madrid"
      },
      {
        "tipo": "oficina",
        "direccion": "calle lagasca 67, Madrid"
      }
    ]
  },
  "rating": 8,
  "genero": ["Accion", "Aventuras"]

},
{
  "nombre": "Pirates of the Caribbean",
  "cast": ["Leonardo Di Caprio", "Johnny Depp", "Jennifer Anniston"],
  "director": {
    "nombre": "Christopher nolan",
    "contacto":[
      {
        "tipo": "personal",
        "direccion": "calle isaac albeniz 15, Madrid"
      },
      {
        "tipo": "oficina",
        "direccion": "calle lagasca 67, Madrid"
      }
    ]
  },
  "rating": 8,
  "genero": ["Accion", "Aventuras"]
}]);
```

Comment: el error es por que estas importando un javascript el `invalid character` es la d de `db.getCollection`

Answer (score 0):

> Para hacer un restore:

1. Una sola Coleccion:

mongorestore --nsInclude base.coleccion dumb/

2. Todas las Colecciones

mongorestore -h 127.0.0.1:27017 -d nuevabase antiguabase

> Para hacer un Backup

1. Una sola Coleccion:

mongodump  -d p -h 127.0.0.1:27017 -d base--collection collection

2. Todas las Colecciones

mongodump -d p -h 127.0.0.1:27017 -d base